# automate input in install.packages()

Tags: r, batch-file, package, installation

I am trying to install package 'gpuR' on R.3.4 on PC. The problem is, when I type install.packages('gpuR') and hit ENTER, the prompt will jump out

Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘gpuR’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?

is there anyway I can automate the input "y" to this prompt?

Comment: You could use `type="source"` to specifically request the source distribution.

Comment: How is this related to Windows [tag:batch-file]s? Please recheck the tags!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a method that checks for a binary first, and then installs by source if unavailable.  I haven't tested it, but something along the lines of

```
install.packages.noprompt <- function (pkgs) {
    binPkgs <- available.packages(type = "binary")
    haveBinary <- pkgs %in% binPkgs
    if (any(haveBinary)) {
        install.packages(pkgs[haveBinary], type = "binary")
    }
    if (!all(haveBinary)) {
        install.packages(pkgs[!haveBinary], type = "source")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this probably won't catch dependencies that are source-only, but the package itself has a binary available.